# Jodorowsky's Dune artbook

Tags: jodorowskys-dune

In the 2013 documentary, [*Jodorowsky's Dune*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jodorowsky%27s_Dune), they show a thick book of art and scenes from the movie that they sent to the studios. They show it in the documentary several times, but I think they mention in it that there weren't many copies of it.

Has the content of that book become publicly available over the years? The only thing that I was able to find online regarding this book is [this page](http://lostmedia.wikia.com/wiki/Dune_(Alejandro_Jodorowsky/Moebius_Screenplay_and_Storyboards;_Frank_Herbert_Screenplay;_Ridley_Scott_Drafts)).

Comment: I'm not 100% sure since I don't still have the book, but I think some of it was included in "Tomorrow and Beyond: Masterpieces of Science Fiction Art", (1978), edited by Ian Summers.  http://www.amazon.com/Tomorrow-Beyond-Masterpieces-Science-Fiction/dp/0894800558

Comment: There's a bunch of images and notes about the design and art direction of the original dune that can be found at http://www.duneinfo.com/unseen

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**No, the content has largely not become publicly available in its entirety**.

[In an interview](http://thedissolve.com/features/interview/452-interview-alejandro-jodorowsky/), Jodorowsky discussed the number of books created:

> **The Dissolve**: You and Seydoux created a massive book that you gave to
>   the studios, showing storyboards and special-effects designs. None of
>   them came back and said, “We don’t want to do this picture with you,
>   but we’re impressed and want to do something else with you”?
>
> **Jodorowsky**: No. ***We made 20 books, and every one we made—they went to
>   MGM, Universal, etc.—the answer at every one of them was,
>   “Jodorowsky’s crazy.”*** Nobody back then would consider doing a 12-hour
>   picture. No one thought about the trilogy until Star Wars came around.
>   In that moment, it was impossible to make a space opera. It was only
>   $7,000 for the rights to the book, it’s nothing, but still nobody
>   wanted to do it.

There are unsubstantiated rumours that only two copies of this "book" still exist, one of which belongs to Jodorowsky. However, he doesn't appear to have discussed this in interviews.

There was some excitement a while back at a typewritten movie script with illustrations that claimed to be "DUNE, screenplay by Alejandro Jorodowsky, adapted from ‘Dune’ by Frank Herbert." However, [Jorodowsky derided it as a fake](http://www.heavymetal.com/news/jodorowsky-says-this-illustrated-dune-script-is-a-fake-so-who-made-it-and-why/).

The most recent information I've seen on the issue is from an [AMA on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/movies/comments/2csd3c/frank_pavich_here_director_of_jodorowskys_dune/) with Frank Pavich, the director of the documentary.

He was asked if the book would be published, and responded:

> There's been talk, yes. I've heard rumblings that Taschen was
>   interested.
>
> I'm not sure where it currently lies. Is it even possible? Can they
>   even get the underlying rights to the novel again? I assume they would
>   need that, at least. Maybe they're waiting for the documentary to
>   spread a little more and go from there?
>
> If it's even published, I'll be first in line at the bookstore, for
>   sure!!

So currently, the content has not become available but *hopefully* it will become available in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Not officially, but some suspiciously unique content is available [here](http://dunebook.wixsite.com/dune).

Comment: That's a great link! Do you know anything else about the book that you can share?